# DHTMLX grid load method not loading data from php file

Tags: javascript, php, dhtmlx

I'm trying to load data from a MySQL database and display it on the dhtmlxgrid.
Here is the code from the HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>my test</title>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="codebase/dhtmlx.css"/>

<script src="codebase/dhtmlx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gridbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    <script>
        mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
        mygrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs");          //the path to images required by grid   
        mygrid.setHeader("uid,username,password, usertype,locname");//the headers of columns        
        mygrid.setInitWidths("100,250,150,100,*");          //the widths of columns     
        mygrid.setColAlign("right,left,left,left,left");       //the alignment of columns
        mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ed,ed,ed,ed");                //the types of columns          
        mygrid.setColSorting("int,str,str,int,str");          //the sorting types 
        mygrid.init();      //finishes initialization and renders the grid on the page 
        mygrid.load("connector.php");  



    </script>
</body>
```

And here is the connector.php file:

```
<?php

require_once("samples/dhtmlxForm/06_data/php/connector/grid_connector.php");//includes related connector file

$res=mysql_connect("localhost","root","anahon1");//connects to server containing the desired DB
mysql_select_db("ssl_pmts");      //connects to the DB. 'sampledb' is the name of our DB
$conn = new GridConnector($res,"MySQL");                     //connector initialization
$conn->dynamic_loading(100);
 $conn->render_table("users","uid","uid,username,password,usertype,locname");

?>
```

And there result index.html file is as:

[image]

If I open the connector.php file directly I get the following:

[image]

The problem is the data is not listed in the grid for some reason. This example should be straight forward but it is not working and I'm new to dhtmlxgrid, so I don't know if it is a setting or a code that I'm missing.

and the table structure is like:

```html
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `usertype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: We ask that code samples and output HTML is provided as text, not images - this is generally good advice everywhere on the web. Here, you can select your code and press the "code" button to format it appropriately. Would you give it a go?

Comment: Sorry about that. Now the code is text.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. The problem was with the size of the div. I changed it to:

```html
<div id="gridbox" style="width:700px;height:700px;"></div>
```

and now it is working. I have no idea why it was not wokring before

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others looking at this post- I had a similar problem where data was being loaded and html was being properly generated(inspect element showed that the cells were being generated and populated, just not shown). It seems that you need to set a height on the #gridbox div.